# infinite loop with react.js and usemutation

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

Hello I have this code :

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import {Modal} from "react-bootstrap";
import {gql, useMutation} from "@apollo/client";

const Activation = (props) => {
    console.log("ABC")  
    const [show, setShow] = useState(true);
    const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
    const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

    const [message, setmessage] = useState("000")

    const GET_ACTIVITY = gql`
    mutation verifyaccount($token: String!){
    verifyAccount(token: $token){
    success,
    errors,
    } 
    }
    `;
    const [addchannel, {loading, error} ] = useMutation(GET_ACTIVITY, {
      onCompleted: (data) => {
          if (data.verifyAccount.success === true){
              setmessage("It is okay");
          }
          else{
              setmessage("It is not okay");
          }

      },
      onError: (error) => console.log("Error", error),
  });
addchannel({
      variables: {
          token: props.match.params.token
      }
  })

    return (
        <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose} centered>
        <div className="login-form">
          <h3 className="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal" style={{textAlign: "center"}}> {message}</h3>
        </div>
      </Modal>
    )
}
export default Activation;
```

Actually, this component is used when I go to a url to confirm an account. Everybody is perfect except that I got the message "It is not okay" because I have a infinite loop. I mean for the first launching I got "It is okay" but then I have only "It is not okay".

I don't understand why I get this infinite loop.

It comes from this part

```
addchannel({
      variables: {
          token: props.match.params.token
      }
  })
```

Because when I remove this part I don't have the infinie loop but the mutation is not executed.

Could you help me please ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: mutation should be called within effect

Comment: Can you explain please ? Thank you

Comment: read about `useEffect` hook?

Comment: I don't understand how useEffect can be useful in my case

Comment: hints: how many times mutation should be run? what causes rerendefing? ... react basic

Comment: Yes but the anwser is just one time

Comment: I mean I load the page and the mutation should be run one time, if I reload the mutation should be run one time again

Comment: Sorry @xadm but I don't understand what you are explaining me. Could you explain me please ?

Comment: I mean copy/paste is not enough without basic react knowledge ... you don't know what effect is for ... you don't know your message (debug method) works against you [in this case] ... I mean you should know what's going on (change/effect/behaviour) in every line, no mercy

Comment: Your `useMutation`'s `onCompleted` callback updates state and triggers a rerender, `useMutation` hook runs again. Rinse & repeat. You probably don't want to be doing this.

Comment: Yes indeed I don't want that... but how can I do to solve that ?

Comment: follow some tutorial about `useEffect` ... SO is not a learning platform :p

Comment: no but it is a helping platform, I tried to use useEffect inside onCompleted but it does not work...

Comment: this breaks hooks rules, next react basic ... next hint: react is data (not event) driven  - I hope it helps .. but you have to help yourself ... this thread already has 2 votes to close ;p

Comment: No you have to help me unless I did not post there... I will be very happy to create another one if I don't have answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be an answer to your question :

Change this :

```
addchannel({
      variables: {
          token: props.match.params.token
      }
  })
```

By :

```
useEffect(() => {addchannel({
      variables: {
          token: props.match.params.token
      }
  })}, []);
```

Comment: @Tom ... but do you 'understand how useEffect can be useful in my case'? how it works? what arg can be used as dependency?